# How to make a trap if '\mathring' command is being used in Tex Document?

Tags: errors, accents

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}

\title{TEST}
\date{}
\maketitle

$\mathring{I}\mathring{J}\ring{I}$
\end{document}
```

Pop up an error if `\mathring` command is being used.

Kindly advise if this feasible in latex.

Answer (score 4):

```
\renewcommand\mathring[1]{\errmessage{DONT USE MATHRING}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine `\mathring` to show an error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{accents}

\renewcommand{\mathring}[1]{%
   \PackageError{mysty}{Don't use \string\mathring!}{- more info -}
}

\begin{document}

\title{TEST}
\date{}
\maketitle

$\mathring{I}\mathring{J}\ring{I}$
\end{document}
```

Obviously `\PackageError` is meant to be used in `.sty` files (as `\ClassError` for `.cls`) but it works here too. It has three arguments:

```
\PackageError{pkg name}{short error message}{extended message}
```

where the extender message is shown, if the user types `H` after the error occurs in the compiling process. In both messages `\string` can be used to type the following command verbatim and you may need `\space` to add a space …